# How to avoid overspecifying fields in queries in graphql while avoiding multiple network requests across pages

Tags: javascript, graphql

If I have two pages, StepsList and StepDetail, I understand it's impossible to avoid overfetching on the first page (StepsList) if we want to avoid a second network request on StepDetail

```
// StepsList
steps {
  id
  name <- I have to specify this field here even if it's not used, to avoid a network request on StepsDetail, where this field is used
}

// StepDetail
steps {
  id
  name
}
```

However, is there a way using a JavaScript graphql client to avoid having to specify the redundant name field on StepsList, while still fetching it, and without using a shared fragment between StepsList and StepDetail? I'm trying to come up with a solution to reduce network requests while still keeping queries specified to the data used by the component they serve.

I don't want to use a shared fragment because I'm finding them unwieldy in a larger project I'm working on.

```
// StepsList
steps {
  id
  # `name` is not specified
  # there is no shared fragment
  # but `name` is still fetched
}

// StepDetail
steps {
  id
  name
}
```

Comment: Using a shared fragment is absolutely the right thing to do here.

Comment: I'm assuming you have 2 pages and you want to reuse the same query?  Why not specify the data you need for each page and run them a separate queries? And if you need to run the query twice for one page (like 2 use cases), you can use aliases on your queries to prevent network overhead on your client.

Comment: @bergi can you show me how you would structure the shared fragments in this case?

Comment: Well you define a `fragment StepDetail on Step { id name }` and use that fragment in both queries? Why do you think they are "unwieldy"?

Comment: @bergi I like being able to explicitly see all of the fields called by a query directly in the query itself (except for when the fields are used by a child component) as it avoids having to reference against another file during development. Secondly, I have a shared fragments file which is 1500 lines, because it's so big I have gotten into some bad habits of duplicating fragments etc which is hard to realize due to it's size. I'm seeking conventions / rules to stop this from happening.

Comment: @jsindos "*when the fields are used by a child component*" is exactly the situation that you're asking about, no? I don't see what's wrong with referencing another file - that's the goal, not a problem. Having 1500 lines in a file, and further growing it by duplicating because it's becoming unwieldy, is of course a problem, and the key issue that you need to solve. Put the fragments in individual files, group them by the type they are defined on or by the component they are used in.

Comment: @bergi sorry I should have specified better, in my question I am referring to two separate root level components on different pages. Thank you for your advice

Comment: @jsindos I had assumed that by "child component" you meant a component that would be loaded later (e.g. as part of a list), and which would do its own query anyway, so it doesn't make a difference imo. In the query in the list component, you specify the fields that you need for displaying the list, *and* you use the fragment with the details, imported from the file where the query for the details component is declared.